# Jade - calling page specific css pages

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug

I have page specific css files I would like to call automatically. Does anyone have a nice way of doing this elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="#{req.path + '.css'}", type="text/css")
```

Where you pass either `req` (the request object) as a local variable when rendering the jade template (or even just pass in `req.path` as `path`).  This could just be handled in your layout.jade and it will work for each of your route paths.

If you want to get fancy, you could establish a consistent pattern where a page's route maps 1 to 1 to a filesystem path for a .css file in your public directory.  In that case you could easily but the stylesheet link tag inside a conditional and only link to the .css file if you find a matching one on disk.

Comment: thanks, for the others I put this in my dynamic helpers:   
 path: function(req, res){
      var path = req.route.path;
      if (path ==='/'){
        return 'home';
      }
      return path;
    }